# Facebook image Format?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, uiimage, nsdata

When you retrieve an image from facebook using the facebook graph api, does anybody know what format it comes in? Is it a PNG or a JPEG file? I want to convert the image as NSData and store it in my database. I'm only asking because there are two commands in swift to convert the image into NSData, i.e. you can use either:

`UIImagePNGRepresentation`

or

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

F.Y.I.

Comment: You can find the type of image from `NSData` itself or from the HTTP response. [more here](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can use this code to display your facebook profile picture in imageview:
```

ivUserProfilePic?.image = UIImage(data: profileData)

we can use UIImagePNGRepresentation and UIImageJPEGRepresentation both.

Comment: i dont want to display the image, I wanted to to store the image as NSData